# tools for Designing a packet filtering system for ipv6

Tags: networking, simulation, packet-capture

So I'm trying to write a software at packet filtering area to manage the security of ipv6 routing header (type 0) , but i'm not sure where to get started, Or what network simulation tools to use .

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! Please note this site is about recommending *software,* not assets or [resources](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2470/185) like [howtos](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/882/185), [manuals/tutorials](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1258/185), etc. – so only the last sentence of your post is on-topic here. And for that we'd need more details, see [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/185)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest taking a look at [Scapy](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/demo.html) which, while not the complete answer will allow you to capture, analyse, create and inject packets, including malformed packets if required.

- Free, Gratis & Open Source.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but is there anything can be used on a windows os.

Comment: And what I'm looking for is simulation (can be used with a simulated network ).

Comment: @AhmedShihab - I use it on windows all of the time! I haven't tried it on a simulated network but if it is a good simulation I wouldn't be surprised if it worked.

Answer (score 0):

## Wireshark

Why don't try [*Wireshark*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireshark)? A must have for analyzing packets including IPV6 packets